# How to hide the search box sharepoint 2013 in style sheet

Tags: search, css

How is it possible to hide the search the site box by amending just the style sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<style type="text/css">
#titleAreaBox #SearchBox{
    display: none !important;
}
</style>
```

Comment: The `!important` part should not be needed in this scenario